# Include manifest variable in SEM without association to any other variable?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

I would like to know whether a model that assumes a correlation between my latent and my manifest variable has a better fit than a similar model without this correlation. I am using SEM for this in the R-package lavaan.

My question concerns the model without the correlation: For a fair comparison of both models, would it be necessary to include the manifest variable without any covariance with other variables? So I would just say "VarManifest ~~ VarManifest" in my lavaan model? I have never seen this done before but it seems plausible to me. Alternatively, I would not have the manifest variable in my model without correlation.

Comment: Yes, models can only be compared when fitted to the same data (in SEM, that means the same mean vector and covariance matrices).  So you fit the constrained model by constraining the relevant parameter(s) to zero, rather than removing a variable.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful